# RestKit returns ErrorDomain Code=-1011 only on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, afnetworking, restkit

I am using RestKit for making https POST request to a REST server. I am pretty sure that I have set the base url, resource path, content-type(json), request and response descriptors correctly, also I have set the Authorization header to RKObjectManager correctly. The code woks fine with no issues when I run the app on any iOS device, but when I run the app on iOS simulator, I get the following error

> restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200), got 400"

I have no clue what causes this error. Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: Probably a simulator bug. Restart it and try again.

Comment: I already tried restarting it many times. It dint help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the log request with :

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

Your URL should be different in simulation mode.

Comment: I enabled trace level logs, but i dont see any difference in the URL and request payload. :-(